# JAVA program always gives the wrong output for the first iteration and then works correctly

Tags: java

I was solving a problem I found on CodeChef -

There are n villages in a line in an area. There are two kinds of tribes A and B that reside there. A village can be either empty or occupied by one of the tribes. An empty village is said to be controlled by a tribe of village A if it is surrounded by villages of tribes A from the left and from the right. Same goes for the tribe B.

Find out the number of villages that are controlled by tribes A and B, respectively.

Input

The first line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases.

The first line of the input contains a string s denoting the configuration of the villages, each character of which can be 'A', 'B' or '.'.

Output

For each test case, output two space separated integers denoting the number of tribes controlled by tribe A and B, respectively.

Example

Input

4
A..A..B...B
..A..
A....A
..B..B..B..

Output

4 5
1 0
6 0
0 7

Here's my code -

import java.util.Scanner;

class Villages_and_Tribes
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter: ");
    int T = sc.nextInt();
    while(T-->0)
    {
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        Villages_and_Tribes obj = new Villages_and_Tribes();
        obj.Count_Villages(s);
    }
}
public void Count_Villages(String s)
{
    int l = s.length();
    int A=0, B=0;
    for(int i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(c=='A')
            A++;
        else if(c=='B')
            B++;
        else
        {
            boolean flagA1 = false, flagB1 = false, flagA2 = false, flagB2 = false;
            for(int j=i+1; j<l; j++)
            {
                char x = s.charAt(j);
                if(x=='A')
                {
                    flagA1 = true;
                    break;
                }
                if(x=='B')
                {
                    flagB1 = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(int k=i-1; k>=0; k--)
            {
                char x = s.charAt(k);
                if(x=='A')
                {
                    flagA2 = true;
                    break;
                }
                if(x=='B')
                {
                    flagB2 = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flagA1==true && flagA2==true)
                A++;
            else if(flagB1==true && flagB2==true)
                B++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(A + " " + B);
}
```

}

Here's my output -

Enter:

4

0 0

A..A..B...B

4 5

..A..

1 0

A....A

6 0

As you can see, the output for T=1 is "0 0". So, if I want four inputs and four corresponding outputs, I need to enter T as 5 instead of 4.

Can anyone care to tell me why this is happening? I would really appreciate your help.

EDIT:

My question's been marked duplicate, but I changed the T-- to simply T and later decreased it using T = T - 1 so as to completely avoid the usage of the decrement operator. However, I get the same results as before. I'm quite sure the error isn't due to the operator usage.

Comment: My question's been marked as duplicate, but I changed the T-- in the program with a simply T and then later decreasing it as T = T-1 so as to completely avoid the decrement operator and I still get the same output.